# Draw NSImage to NSOpenGLView

Tags: cocoa, opengl, render, nsimage, nsopenglview

I'm trying to basically implement a NSImageView using NSOpenGLView. I mean, it should be able to render from a provided NSImage.
Could anyone provide me a simple OpenGL implementation or some starting guide lines?